# Screen starts flickering when in streaming

Tags: mac, screen, streaming

I have this problem that now I am really getting bothered from it. It always starts when I am streaming something on the web like YouTube videos and open other programs which I have to work with like Matlab or some others. Then my screen goes crazy , but it not constantly, it looks like cracking a mirror , attached some screenshots.

Kindly help me cause I am really getting annoyed about this.

P.S. I have MacBook Pro retina early 2015 with Mojave 10.14 , but it used to be like this even with High Sierra. 
Any help is really appreciated,

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Hardware issues don‘t show up in screenshots usually, unless the RAM in the CPU is somehow broken. If the reinstall proposed below doesn‘t help it‘s probably time to bring it to a store for maintenance.

Comment: Try a safe boot.
    Shutdown your machine.  Hold down the shift key.  Poweron.  The boot up will take longer than normal because the filesystem on the startup drive is being checked and repaired as needed.   All about safe mode including what features and apps safe boot leaves out. Safe boot uses a software driver instead of using your machines video hardware.
      http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455

Answer (score 2):

**Your problem**

If the problem appears on screenshots, then that would mean it's most likely a software problem. There can be a lot of reasons for this to occur and it's not possible to deduce from your story what causes it in this case.

**Possible solution**

I would advice you to reinstall macOS and see if that solves your problem.
[Instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)

Answer (score 0):

Unless it has gotten abused, I'd say it is either a glitch, or retina damage. If it is a glitch, I'd also advise reinstalling MacOS, after doing so, if it still does this you're gonna need a new screen!